# Transfer of angular velocity in Oldham's coupling with the centre disc not sliding

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

In Oldham coupling,is it possible that the same angular velocity is transferred from one shaft to the other when the centre disc is not sliding?If so,why do we want the centre disc to slide?I know that the shafts are misaligned but it is occurring to me that the same motion is possible when the centre disc is held back from sliding?

Comment: if you fix the middle disc how will it then rotate?

Comment: Rotating one disc would cause  a rotation in centre disc as it is projected into it and consequently centre disc rotates third disc since it is also projected into third disc.why isn't this possible?

Comment: It is only held back from sliding,not from rotating

Comment: Why don't you plot the relative motion and see how the rotation interacts with sliding and vice versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plot the center of the third disc in one revolution you'll see it moves in a circle with diameter $δk$  with $δk$
 the radial deviation of the two shafts. So if you fix the disc, it can't compensate the radial deviation at all. If i remember the frequency of the disc is about twice as it frequency of the shafts.[image]

[image]

The Oldham coupling is a kind of cross disc coupling (German). The second figure shows the general principal behind this soort of couplings.